# I'm having trouble programming my bulls and cows game in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a novice programmer and I've been using JavaScript to make a simple game of Bulls and Cows that updates with the amount of Bulls and Cows you have in a paragraph with each guess. I've been using "'1234'" in place of "arr.join("")" to test it out, and it's almost there, but it's adding one bull by default and not taking into account the first digit of the number being submitted. When I submit the correct number, everything comes up fine. I just wanted to know why I don't seem to be getting the proper amount of bulls and cows.

```js
// This is our click counter that tells you how many times you've guessed in the game.

var clicks = 0;
$("#submit").click(function() {
  clicks++;
  $("#guesses").html(clicks);
});

// Generates a non-repeating, random number and stores it in a global variable known as "secret".

$("#start").click(function() {
  var arr = [];
  while (arr.length < 4) {
    var randomnumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9);
    var found = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i] === randomnumber) {
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!found) arr[arr.length] = randomnumber;
  }
  secret = "1234";
});

// When you click the "Hide Rules" button, it hides the Rules form and shows the "Show Rules" button.

$("#hide").click(function() {
  $("#rulesform").hide();
  $("#show").show();
  $("#hide").hide();
});

// When you click the "Show Rules" button, it shows the rules form and the "Hide Rules" button and hides the "Show Rules" button.

$("#show").click(function() {
  $("#rulesform").show();
  $("#show").hide();
  $("#hide").show();
});

// When you click "Start playing!", it hides the button, shows the game, sets guesses equal to 0, and generates the number for the game.

$("#start").click(function() {
  $("#game").show();
  $("#start").hide();
  $("#submit").show();
  $("#guesses").html("0");
});

// When you hit the "Stop playing." button, it clears the results of the game and guess input box, in addition to hiding the game functions and showing the "Start playing!" button.

$("#stop").click(function() {
  $("#game").hide();
  $("#start").show();
  $("#results").html("");
  $("#guess").val("");
  clicks = 0;
});

function game() {

  // Stores your guess in a variable

  var guess = $("#guess").val();

  // Makes sure the number is 4 digits

  if (guess.length != 4) {
    alert("This number is too long or short to be valid.");
  }

  // Makes sure the numbers are non-repeating if they're 4 digits.
  else if (guess.charAt(1) === guess.charAt(2) || guess.charAt(1) === guess.charAt(3) || guess.charAt(1) === guess.charAt(4) || guess.charAt(2) === guess.charAt(3) || guess.charAt(2) === guess.charAt(4) || guess.charAt(3) === guess.charAt(4)) {
    alert("This game doesn't have any repeating digits.");
  }

  // This is the actual game.
  else {

    // These two variables will be updated with each guess the user inputs.

    var bulls = 0;
    var cows = 0;

    // This is where JavaScript checks the bulls and cows and adds them up accordingly.

    if (guess !== secret) {
      if (guess.charAt(1) === secret.charAt(1)) {
        bulls += 1;
      } else if (guess.charAt(1) === secret.charAt(2) || guess.charAt(1) === secret.charAt(3) || guess.charAt(1) === secret.charAt(4)) {
        cows += 1;
      }
      if (guess.charAt(2) === secret.charAt(2)) {
        bulls += 1;
      } else if (guess.charAt(2) === secret.charAt(1) || guess.charAt(2) === secret.charAt(3) || guess.charAt(2) === secret.charAt(4)) {
        cows += 1;
      }
      if (guess.charAt(3) === secret.charAt(3)) {
        bulls += 1;
      } else if (guess.charAt(3) === secret.charAt(1) || guess.charAt(3) === secret.charAt(2) || guess.charAt(3) === secret.charAt(4)) {
        cows += 1;
      }
      if (guess.charAt(4) === secret.charAt(4)) {
        bulls += 1;
      } else if (guess.charAt(4) === secret.charAt(1) || guess.charAt(4) === secret.charAt(2) || guess.charAt(4) === secret.charAt(3)) {
        cows += 1;
      }
      $("#results").html("Bulls: " + bulls + " & Cows: " + cows + "");
    } else if (guess === secret) {
      $("#results").html("<strong>Congrats, you won! <a href='images/cookie.gif'>Here's a picture</a> of a cookie.</strong>");
      $("#submit").hide();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <h1>Want to play a game?</h1>
  <div id="rules">
    <form id="rulesform">
      <h2>Rules:</h2>
      <p>The computer will generate a random 4-digit number without any of them repeating. You will do your best to guess the number in the input field provided. If a digit you entered is not used, you will not get any bulls or cows. If it's in the correct
        spot, then you'll get 1 bull. If it's in the wrong spot, it will be a cow. The game ends when you guess the number. The amount of guesses it takes for you to figure it out will be provided.</p>
    </form>
    <input type="button" id="hide" value="Hide Rules">
    <input type="button" id="show" value="Show Rules">
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="start" value="Start playing!">
  </div>
  <!--closes rules-->
  <div id="game">
    <input type="number" id="guess" placeholder="Your Guess">
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit your guess." onclick="game()">
    <br>
    <p id="guesstext">Guesses:</p>
    <p id="guesses"></p>
    <p id="results"></p>
    <input type="button" id="stop" value="Stop playing.">
  </div>
  <!--closes game-->
</div>
<!--closes wrapper-->
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. share your code over [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), please. It becomes easy to share and edit and discuss.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first character in a string is charAt(0) in that string, not charAt(1). Reduce all your charAt references by one and see if that works.

Here's what it should look like:

```js
// This is our click counter that tells you how many times you've guessed in the game.

var clicks = 0;
$("#submit").click(function() {
  clicks++;
  $("#guesses").html(clicks);
});

// Generates a non-repeating, random number and stores it in a global variable known as "secret".

$("#start").click(function() {
  var arr = [];
  while (arr.length < 4) {
    var randomnumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9);
    var found = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i] === randomnumber) {
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!found) arr[arr.length] = randomnumber;
  }
  window.secret = "1234";
});

// When you click the "Hide Rules" button, it hides the Rules form and shows the "Show Rules" button.

$("#hide").click(function() {
  $("#rulesform").hide();
  $("#show").show();
  $("#hide").hide();
});

// When you click the "Show Rules" button, it shows the rules form and the "Hide Rules" button and hides the "Show Rules" button.

$("#show").click(function() {
  $("#rulesform").show();
  $("#show").hide();
  $("#hide").show();
});

// When you click "Start playing!", it hides the button, shows the game, sets guesses equal to 0, and generates the number for the game.

$("#start").click(function() {
  $("#game").show();
  $("#start").hide();
  $("#submit").show();
  $("#guesses").html("0");
});

// When you hit the "Stop playing." button, it clears the results of the game and guess input box, in addition to hiding the game functions and showing the "Start playing!" button.

$("#stop").click(function() {
  $("#game").hide();
  $("#start").show();
  $("#results").html("");
  $("#guess").val("");
  clicks = 0;
});

window.game = function() {

  // Stores your guess in a variable

  var guess = $("#guess").val();

  // Makes sure the number is 4 digits

  if (guess.length != 4) {
    alert("This number is too long or short to be valid.");
  }

  // Makes sure the numbers are non-repeating if they're 4 digits.
  else if (guess.charAt(0) === guess.charAt(1) || guess.charAt(0) === guess.charAt(2) || guess.charAt(0) === guess.charAt(3) || guess.charAt(1) === guess.charAt(2) || guess.charAt(1) === guess.charAt(3) || guess.charAt(2) === guess.charAt(3)) {
    alert("This game doesn't have any repeating digits.");
  }

  // This is the actual game.
  else {

    // These two variables will be updated with each guess the user inputs.

    var bulls = 0;
    var cows = 0;

    // This is where JavaScript checks the bulls and cows and adds them up accordingly.

    if (guess !== secret) {
      if (guess.charAt(0) === secret.charAt(0)) {
        bulls += 1;
      } else if (guess.charAt(0) === secret.charAt(1) || guess.charAt(0) === secret.charAt(2) || guess.charAt(0) === secret.charAt(3)) {
        cows += 1;
      }
      if (guess.charAt(1) === secret.charAt(1)) {
        bulls += 1;
      } else if (guess.charAt(1) === secret.charAt(0) || guess.charAt(1) === secret.charAt(2) || guess.charAt(1) === secret.charAt(3)) {
        cows += 1;
      }
      if (guess.charAt(2) === secret.charAt(2)) {
        bulls += 1;
      } else if (guess.charAt(2) === secret.charAt(0) || guess.charAt(2) === secret.charAt(1) || guess.charAt(2) === secret.charAt(3)) {
        cows += 1;
      }
      if (guess.charAt(3) === secret.charAt(3)) {
        bulls += 1;
      } else if (guess.charAt(3) === secret.charAt(0) || guess.charAt(3) === secret.charAt(1) || guess.charAt(3) === secret.charAt(2)) {
        cows += 1;
      }
      $("#results").html("Bulls: " + bulls + " & Cows: " + cows + "");
    } else if (guess === secret) {
      $("#results").html("<strong>Congrats, you won! <a href='images/cookie.gif'>Here's a picture</a> of a cookie.</strong>");
      $("#submit").hide();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This was my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this, though. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not really on the topic, but I had to do the same task and found your code a really useful example. I kinda edited it and suggest you, something, that is far better option in my opinion(It is not necessary to be the better option, just my point of view)

```
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if(String(guess).charAt(i) == String(number).charAt(i)){
        bulls++;
    }else{
        for (var j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            if ((String(guess).charAt(i) == String(number).charAt(j)) && (i !== j)) {
                cows++;
            };
        };
    }
};
```

Where guess is your guess and number is the generated number.
The above code might be put instead of

```
      if (guess.charAt(0) === secret.charAt(0)) {
    bulls += 1;
    } else if (guess.charAt(0) === secret.charAt(1) || guess.charAt(0) === secret.charAt(2) || guess.charAt(0) === secret.charAt(3)) {
    cows += 1;
  }
  if (guess.charAt(1) === secret.charAt(1)) {
    bulls += 1;
  } else if (guess.charAt(1) === secret.charAt(0) || guess.charAt(1) === secret.charAt(2) || guess.charAt(1) === secret.charAt(3)) {
    cows += 1;
  }
  if (guess.charAt(2) === secret.charAt(2)) {
    bulls += 1;
  } else if (guess.charAt(2) === secret.charAt(0) || guess.charAt(2) === secret.charAt(1) || guess.charAt(2) === secret.charAt(3)) {
    cows += 1;
  }
  if (guess.charAt(3) === secret.charAt(3)) {
    bulls += 1;
  } else if (guess.charAt(3) === secret.charAt(0) || guess.charAt(3) === secret.charAt(1) || guess.charAt(3) === secret.charAt(2)) {
    cows += 1;
  }
```

I hope, I helped.